# Can I convert an open ended tuple a closed tuple?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the following code to work:

```js
interface AstNode<T> {
  value: T;
}

const n1: AstNode<number> = { value: 1 };
const n2: AstNode<string> = { value: "asdf" };

// https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26063 says that if T is a tuple
// type, the mapped type will map each specific type in the tuple.
type Values<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends AstNode<infer V> ? V : never };

function node<
  T,
  // https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897 allows open ended tuple types, and
  // I want D to be open-ended here.
  D extends [...AstNode<any>[]],
  // But then here I want to convert it back to fixed-length to get [string, number] instead
  // of [string | number, string | number]
  A extends Values<D>
>(deps: D, fn: (...args: A) => T): AstNode<T> {
  const values = deps.map(d => d.value) as A;
  return { value: fn(...values) };
}

const n3: AstNode<string> = node([n1, n2], (v1, v2) => {
  const v1n: number = v1; // v1 is string | number
  const v2s: string = v2; // v2 is string | number
  return v1n + v2s;
});
```

Which I believe is really just a generalization of the `Promise.all` problem, where `Promise.all` would like to be declared with a single open-length tuple of generic types, and it's return value would be a mapped type over the *fixed-length* version of the original/inferred tuple.

Is something like this possible yet in TypeScript? Is there a specific issue tracking this capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really think your issue is about open-ended tuples vs fixed-length here.  For anyone who actually needs this, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223) suggesting more ability to manipulate tuple types, where I [mused](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223#issuecomment-410847836) that it would be nice to be able to specify strict tuples of a given length and open-ended tuples of a given prefix length.  There doesn't seem to be much going on there though.  Currently the language does not natively support this; you can probably fake up something yourself which at least works for tuples up to some reasonable maximum length, if you need it.

---

Probably the main problem is that TypeScript will not automatically infer an array literal like `[n1, n2]` to be of a tuple type such as `[AstNode<number>, AstNode<string>]`; instead it will tend to infer an array type such as `Array<AstNode<number> | AstNode<string>>`, which loses ordering and length information and results in `number | string`.

Here's how I might type `node()`:

```
function node<T, A extends any[]>(
  deps: { [K in keyof A]: AstNode<A[K]> } | [never],
  fn: (...args: A) => T
): AstNode<T> {
  const values = (deps as Array<AstNode<any>>).map(d => d.value) as A;
  return { value: fn(...values) };
}
```

Notice that I'm doing the reverse tuple mapping from yours, where I calculate `D` given `A`, as opposed to `A` given `D`.  Also note that there's no real reason to have two type parameters for those; you don't need the extra degree of freedom since once you have `A`, you know `D`, so I've removed it.

The fix to the main problem comes from that `| [never]` at the end of the `deps` type.  It doesn't really do much in terms of what values for `deps` are allowed (since I hope there are no one-tuples with a `never` element floating around our code), but it does [give the compiler a hint that you want it to be inferred as a tuple type](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990).  Yes, it's not pretty; it would be better if there were some [less hacky way to ask for tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680), but there isn't (at least as of TS3.6).

Also note that the new type of `deps` is a little weird, so I changed it to `(deps as Array<AstNode<any>>)` when calling the `map()` method.

Well, let's see how it works:

```
const n3: AstNode<string> = node([n1, n2], (v1, v2) => {
  const v1n: number = v1; // okay
  const v2s: string = v2; // okay
  return v1n + v2s;
});
```

Looks good.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIGcwDkD2ATCAHgBUA+ZAbwFgAoZZANzgBsBXCALmWIG5aBfWrQQ4QmZCACMXDNnxEQrALYAjaOQC8lRi3ZdJyfnxoixYCQCYZmXAUKYooAOabtTNp2QAiOOjwwvQ2NaGFYQBDBgUQl5EgAaNGQIAA9IEDx0ZDgQAE8AbQBdUgAKWnoCAAd0LgpkPIBpZFBkAGsIHJwYNALrOTtUBqLDZAAfOpAIBmgCuLLkGBAuYoA6VbgoJ2q0AEpkDXJiWm3e2yIySjnTcXd2TK1iyszfNCgoOBzCWVPCbJzSUm2yyUcAqDz25DwyxuEF2z1QxnoUAgYFYUBAbl0ngWK1W0PQuyMAiEJlE4hAAGYTrEHM5XCB5MU8lIEiALDNkMUGJIEgwLLt9hc6MgruYuYsJMo1FA9oxJDxkAB6BXIHAtd6XUmiixbGkgJwy3nypUqtU5OZIlFo2XogDUjG1xn422MQA)

Comment: Wow, thanks! The `[never]` trick is exactly what I needed. I like your point that I don't need both `D` and `A`. I'll go with that. Although also turns that that doing `deps: D | [never]` in my original version also kicks over the inference into tuple mode (just for my own understanding/generalization/sanity checking).